# There is no metric that makes the integral curves of the field $X=(y,-x)$ geodesics?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, geodesic

I used the fact that $\nabla_X X=0$, which implies that the integral curves of $X$ are geodesics, to find the Christoffel symbols(the non-zero ones are $\Gamma_{22}^1=1/x,\Gamma_{11}^2=1/y$). I then used $\nabla g=0$ to find the metric from the connection, but I get a singular metric, which cannot happen.

But I hoped I'd get the metric of a cylinder as the solution, as if the metric is that of a cylinder, this vector field corresponds to revolutions around the cylinder, which are geodesics. What is wrong with what I'm doing or with the interpretation?

Comment: Your underlying manifold is punctured plane?

Comment: @C.F.G Nope. I did it with $\mathbb R^2$. At the origin I get the zero metric.

Comment: @C.F.G Should I restrict the metric to not be defined on $(0,0)$, so for example, using the field $(y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2},-x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$?

Comment: What do you mean "I did it with ... "? You must first fix a manifold, then a vector field on it then try to find metric or connection. So, I ask again here What is your underlying manifold?

Comment: @C.F.G It's $\mathbb R^2$. The field then is defined on the whole plane. Is that the error? But I mean, the field is a valid field in the punctured plane too. Edit: By using the trivial chart.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2799480/272127).

Comment: Can you calculate derivation of integral curve in $(0,0)$ when $M=\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @C.F.G Well, no, the Christoffel symbols are not defined at that point. So the covariant derivative is not defined. But does the setting change much when restricting the space to the punctured plane? I mean, my setting is that I have a vector field on a smooth manifold(which now doesn't contain $(0,0)$) which has the trivial chart to $\mathbb R^2$(I believe this is a smooth manifold), and I need to solve for the metric. Edit: Also, the only integral curve that passes from $(0,0)$ in this field is the trivial path which stays at that point, so I could just get rid of it(I think).

Comment: Try it! Everything seems to be ok! But remember that answer may not be unique. if $g$ is a solution then $\lambda g$ is also a solution.

Comment: The punctured plane, where all concentric circles are geodesics, looks very similar to a cylinder right?

Comment: @C.F.G Okay, I will try the new setting. Thanks :)

Comment: @Didier Yes, it does.

Comment: @Garmekain Then you should be able to find a metric that works on the punctured plane thanks to this idea

Comment: @Didier What I have trouble with, is that if the topology of the punctured plane is the topology inherited from the standard one, how the metric is different from the one I have. I mean, the punctured plane is open in the standard topology, so the trivial chart should suffice, and so my solution(or any scaled one) should be valid, which isn't.

Comment: @Garmekain Everything is open in its own topology.
Moreover, the cylinder and the punctured plane are diffeomorphic, both to $S^1\times \Bbb R$ (or $S^1 \times (0,1)$, or with any open interval on the right)

Comment: @Didier Well, I'm working with a certain topology here.

Comment: Perhaps someone already pointed this out, but the question itself tells you that the origin must be excluded. The vector field $X$ vanishes at the origin, and a geodesic cannot consist just of a single point.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to use polar coordinates.

The geodesics of the metric
$$\tag{1}
ds^2=dr^2+d\theta^2
$$
are
straight lines in $(r,\theta)$ because the Christoffel symbols all vanish. Among those geodesics are

- rays going through the origin
  $r\mapsto (r,\theta)\,,$ where the angle $\theta$ is fixed, and
- circles
  $\theta\mapsto (r,\theta)\,$ where the radius $r$ is fixed.

To see how this metric looks like in Cartesian coordinates we start
from
\begin{align}\tag{2}
dx&=\cos\theta\,dr-r\sin\theta\,d\theta\,,&dy=\sin\theta\,dr+r\cos\theta\,d\theta
\end{align}
and get
\begin{align}\tag{3}
\begin{pmatrix}dr\\r\,d\theta\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}dx\\dy\end{pmatrix}\,,
\end{align}
which can be written as
\begin{align}\tag{4}
dr&=\cos\theta\,dx+\sin\theta\,dy\,,&d\theta=\frac{-\sin\theta\,dx+\cos\theta\,dy}{r}\,.
\end{align}
Therefore, the metric in Cartesian coordinates is
\begin{align}
ds^2&=\Big(\cos^2\theta+\frac{\sin^2\theta}{r^2}\Big)\,dx^2+\Big(\sin^2\theta+\frac{\cos^2\theta}{r^2}\Big)\,dy^2
+2\sin\theta\cos\theta\Big(1-\frac{1}{r^2}\Big)\,dx\,dy\nonumber\\
&=\frac{x^2r^2+y^2}{r^4}\,dx^2+\frac{y^2r^2+x^2}{r^4}\,dy^2+2xy\frac{r^2-1}{r^4}\,dx\,dy\tag{5}
\end{align}
where the abbreviation $r^2=x^2+y^2$ is used.

With `sympy` I calculated the Christoffel symbols:
\begin{align*}
{\Gamma^x}_{xx} &= - \frac{x y^2}{r^4}\,,&{\Gamma^x}_{xy} &={\Gamma^x}_{yx}= - \frac{y^3}{r^4}\,,&{\Gamma^x}_{yy} &= \frac{(x^2 + 2 y^2) x}{r^4}\,,\\
{\Gamma^y}_{xx} &= \frac{(2 x^2 + y^2) y}{r^4}\,,&{\Gamma^y}_{xy} &={\Gamma^y}_{yx}= - \frac{x^3}{r^4}\,,&{\Gamma^y}_{yy} &= - \frac{x^2 y}{r^4}\,.
\end{align*}
To check that circles are geodesics lets parametrize them by
$$\tag{6}
x(\theta)=r\cos(\theta)\,,\quad y(\theta)=r\sin(\theta)
$$
and observe that
the equations of motion are
$$\tag{7}
\ddot x=-x\,,\quad \ddot y=-y\,.
$$
The geodesic equation are, as we know:
\begin{align*}
0&=\ddot x+{\Gamma^x}_{xx}\,\dot x^2+{\Gamma^x}_{yy}\,\dot y^2+{\Gamma^x}_{xy}\,\dot x\dot y+{\Gamma^x}_{yx}\,\dot x\dot y\,,\tag{8}\\[2mm]
0&=\ddot y+{\Gamma^y}_{xx}\,\dot x^2+{\Gamma^y}_{yy}\,\dot y^2+{\Gamma^y}_{xy}\,\dot x\dot y+{\Gamma^y}_{yx}\,\dot x\dot y\,.\tag{9}
\end{align*}
Since
\begin{align*}
\dot x=-y\,,\quad \dot y =x\tag{10}
\end{align*}
we get
\begin{align}
0&=\ddot x+{\Gamma^x}_{xx}\,y^2+{\Gamma^x}_{yy}\,x^2-{\Gamma^x}_{xy}\,xy-{\Gamma^x}_{yx}\,xy\,,\tag{11}\\[2mm]
0&=\ddot y+{\Gamma^y}_{xx}\,y^2+{\Gamma^y}_{yy}\,x^2-{\Gamma^y}_{xy}\,xy-{\Gamma^y}_{yx}\,xy\,.\tag{12}
\end{align}

Plugging the Christoffel symbols into (11) and (12) gives
\begin{align*}
0&=\ddot x+\frac{-xy^4+x^5+2x^3y^2+2xy^4}{r^4}=\ddot x+x\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{r^4}=\ddot x+x\,,\tag{13}\\
0&=\ddot y+\frac{2x^2y^3+y^5-x^4y+2x^4y}{r^4}=\ddot y+y\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{r^4}=\ddot y+y\,.\tag{14}
\end{align*}
which are the equations of motion (7) as it should be.

Again with `sympy` I also checked that the Riemann tensor of the
metric (5) vanishes as it must.

***A pseudo Riemannian Metric***

The pseudo Riemannian metric
$$\tag{15}
g=\begin{pmatrix}xy^{-1}&0\\0&-yx^{-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$
leads to
\begin{align*}
{\Gamma^x}_{xx}&=\frac{1}{2x}\,, &{\Gamma^x}_{yy}&=-\frac{y^2}{2x^3}\,,&{\Gamma^x}_{xy}&=-\frac{1}{2y}\,,&{\Gamma^x}_{yx}&=-\frac{1}{2y}\,,\\[2mm]
{\Gamma^y}_{xx}&=-\frac{x^2}{2y^3}\,, &{\Gamma^y}_{yy}&=\frac{1}{2y}\,,&{\Gamma^y}_{xy}&=-\frac{1}{2x}\,,&{\Gamma^x}_{yx}&=-\frac{1}{2x}\,.
\end{align*}
Then the geodesic equations collapse again to the equations of motion (7) that the circles satisfy.

Comment: I see the error, I tried to guess the Christoffel symbols from (10) and (11), with no luck. When I check the answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Garmekain I just fixed two minor typos in (9) and (12). The Chrstoffels should have $y$ as their upper index. No effect on the results.

Comment: Note that polar coordinates preclude from the start including the origin in the manifold.

Comment: @TedShifrin Of course. The equations (11) and (12) are probably a start where the origin is still in the domain of a possible metric. But if we want Christoffels that reduce those equations to $0=\ddot x+x$ and $0=\ddot y+y$ then it seems that they must have singularities at the origin.