# Question about dimensionality of radians and their function when double integrating in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

When integrating differential forms, we know classically that

$$ dx  \, dy = -dy \, dx$$

Which geometrically comes from the orientation of an area formed by the two forms, such that the counter-clockwise motion from $dx$ to $dy$ defines a positive area, and so forth.

Radians are typically given as being a dimensionless and unitless quantity, but observe the following integral expressed in polar coordinates:

$$ \int_\limits{\theta} \int_\limits{r} dr \, d\theta$$

---

(i) Does it hold still that $dr \, d\theta = - d\theta \, dr$? Furthermore, while in the cartesian coordinates $dx , dy$ we can see that walking in some direction has a vector-like quality to it, which extends to tangent bundles and makes integrals obvious.

(ii) If radians are truly dimensionless then how do you extend the wedge product to $d \theta$ and $dr$? Even neglecting integration and differentiation, are you not allowed to put a vector field on a surface given in polar coordinates? If either are true, it seems there must be a dimensional and oriented quantity associated with a displacement in the $\theta$-direction. Neglecting all formalism, I can intuitively walk counter-clockwise around a circle (positive radian displacement) and then walk clockwise instead (negative radian displacement).

---

What then would give radians any less legitimacy as a dimensional unit than meters or joules? Or perhaps the 360 degrees of the circle, where there's a similarity between the conversion of radians to degrees as there is for the conversion of Celsius to Fahrenheit.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Don’t omit the wedges. $dx\wedge dy=-dy\wedge dx$, yes. Likewise, $dr\wedge d\theta=-d\theta\wedge dr$. As far as units go, $dr\wedge d\theta$ has ‘units of area in parameter space’ (whatever this vague statement means) whereas the ‘units of area in physical space’ are provided by $r\,dr\wedge d\theta$. But really, trying to assign units to coordinates is not really a fruitful way of thinking (because we often use coordinates which have different units).

Comment: @peek-a-boo I think you could just post hat as an answer.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Then we can at least say that the concept of an "angle" isn't dimensionless in polar coordinates, seeing that there's a clear notion of orientation that $d\theta$ needs in order for it to induce an orientation in the wedge product $dr  \wedge d\theta$? As a note, I'm viewing "dimensionless" as being analogous to a 0-form, and someone may correct me if I'm wrong in thinking that.

Comment: You should first clarify what you mean by "dimensionless". Not carrying a physical unit, or what else? Why can't $0$-forms (functions) not have physical units? Other than that I'd recommend to follow peek-a-boo's advice and not assign such units to coordinates at all.

Comment: @peek-a-boo, I've learned that in fact using units is quite useful in differential geometry. In general, the only units are for length, area, volume, etc. A coordinate function has units of length, and a coordinate vector field has units of 1/length. Keeping track of this is extremely useful when doing calculations.

Comment: Units are useful only in a geometric setting. In such a setting, you rarely if ever have an integral of the form $$\int \text{ constant }\,dr\,d\theta $$ for exactly the reason you state. If the space is flat, the integral is almost always of the form $$\int f(r,\theta)\,r\,dr\wedge d\theta.$$ Here, $f$ might have units but they would not be of distance, so the integral has units of length squared, i.e, area.

Comment: @KurtG., I used to always wonder if $x$ has units of length, what would be the units of, say, $e^x$ are. What I finally realized is that the input and output of a nonlinear function are always unitless (which is why the nonlinearity does not lead to inconsistencies). And, in a geometric or physical setting, you never actually see $e^x$, where $x$ has units. You always really have $e^{x/c}$, where $c$ is a constant with the same units as $x$. You usually can see this by rescaling $x$ (which is equivalent to changing the units from, say, inches to centimeters).

Comment: @Deane That is a good point. In the mean time I was thinking about OP's $dr\wedge d\theta\,.$ There is a weird but still interesting [manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4714294/there-is-no-metric-that-makes-the-integral-curves-of-the-field-x-y-x-geodes/4714792#4714792) that has this as volume form, and equivalently $ds^2=dr^2+d\theta^2$ as metric. If we want to have units of length we should in this case allow $d\theta$ to have that. I think what happens is that from the classic $r\,dr\wedge d\theta$ (with $r$ having length) we divide out a dimensionless $r$ ...

Comment: ... to get $dr\wedge d\theta\,.$ Not sure if this all makes sense. If not I go back to peek-a-boo's camp. :)

Comment: @KurtG, if a metric is written $dp^2 + dq^2$ then by definition, $p$ and $q$ must have units of length.